# What is the grammatical form of the sentence after the word "paradox"

Tags: sentence-construction, subordinate-clauses

This is a sentence on the book "1100 Words You Need to Know" Week 1 Day 3. I can understand the meaning of the sentence perfectly but the sentence structure and grammatical rules are a bit weird for me after the word **paradox**.

> Sylvia regularly took a crowded subway train to work during rush hour, so **she found it to be a "paradox" one hot, steamy Tuesday to easily find a seat in a car that was nearly empty**.

When we say "she found it to be **a**", we must use a noun or a noun phrase after "**a**" but is "paradox one hot, steamy Tuesday to easily find a seat in a car that was nearly empty" a noun phrase?

Shouldn't we say instead "she found it a paradox that in a hot, steamy Tuesday she could find a seat in a car that was nearly empty"?

----Edit ( I write the full text below. It may help )

> Sylvia regularly took a crowded subway train to work during rush hour,
> so **she found it to be a paradox one hot, steamy Tuesday to easily find
> a seat in a car that was nearly empty**. She wondered how, in the realm
> of possibilities, this could be; how often in the annals of subway
> history had there been such a fortunate occurrence? To compound the
> puzzle, looking out the window she could see many commuters busily
> racing on the platform to fill other cars. It was not until she saw
> the sign on the door that she realized, with a tinge of resignation,
> why she had been so “lucky” this morning: “We apologize, but the air
> conditioning is not working in this car.”

Comment: I would have said "on a hot ..." but otherwise your version could be argued to be more natural.

Comment: I would have said *so she found it "paradoxical" that she easily found a seat in a car that was nearly empty, on one hot, steamy Tuesday*. Though it doesn't look like a very good way to illustrate what ***paradox/ical*** means - why should that be a useful word for describing the fact that for some unspecified reason the subway wasn't as busy as usual? And why mention the weather or the day of the week?

Comment: **paradox** is certainly a noun, so yes, it is a noun phrase.

Comment: @stangdon I didi not ask if "paradox" is a noun phrase. I asked if the whole expression "paradox one hot, steamy Tuesday to easily find a seat in a car that was nearly empty" is a noun phrase because it comes after "a"

Comment: @OmidSadeghi  That's what I'm saying, though.  **a paradox to find an X** is certainly a noun phrase, because it's all just modifying **a paradox**.

Comment: "a paradox ... to easily find a seat in a car that was nearly empty" is an NP with  "paradox" as head and the infinitival clause as its complement

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I know such structure but what is the role of "one hot, steamy Tuesday"

Comment: It's a temporal adjunct.

Comment: **What a terrible sentence**. It should be something like: [...] one steamy hot Tuesday she was lucky,  easily finding a seat in a nearly empty car. But even so, the ideas in it are just, plain bad. She was lucky, and the situation is not a "paradox". Those two to's really take the cake.

Comment: And I don't think a book with that title has a "Lesson 3".

Comment: @Lambie you're right. It has weeks and days instead of lessons. I edited my question. This part is on Week 1 Lesson 3.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi I do not understand how a book about vocabulary has text like that. By like that, I mean, in such poor English. Are you sure you got the right book and title? I see many red flags in that text.

Comment: @Lambie This is the link of the book: https://www.amazon.com/1100-Words-You-Need-Know-dp-1438010427/dp/1438010427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylvia regularly took a crowded subway train to work during rush hour, so she found it to be a "paradox" one hot, steamy Tuesday to easily find a seat in a car that was nearly empty.

- 1. I would never have used the word paradox here. But never mind, the author did.
- 2. Don't be misled by: **one hot, steamy Tuesday**, which is adverbial (**when** she found it paradoxical) and could have been placed elsewhere:

In order to see how it works, we can write it like this:
[...] so she found it, one hot, steamy Tuesday, to be a "paradox" to easily find a seat in a car that was nearly empty.

- 3. to find something to be something
- 4. to easily find a seat in a car that was nearly empty.= a **to-infinitive clause**

AND:

1. First, the "it" is the rheme in the sentence, and the infinitive clause is the theme.

More about how that works here (very useful, by the way): [**theme/rheme construction**](https://www.facebook.com/LINGUISTCS/posts/theme-and-rheme-systematic-functional-grammarthe-themerheme-construction-has-bee/1885471485061691/)

2. For me, **the following would be grammatical**:

- to find it to be a paradox that she was able to so easily find a seat.

3. - For me, this is ungrammatical or **at the least very awkward**:
     to find it to be a paradox to easily find a seat in a car.

Generally speaking, constructions with "to find it to be an x" with a theme/rheme construction sound awful when followed by a to-infinitive and are better structured with a subordinate clause.

- I find **it** to be a mistake **that** a sentence like this is given as an example to students.

And not:

- I find **it to be a mistake to give** a sentence like this as an example to students.

**Better**: I find giving a sentence like this as an example to students to be a mistake.

Using two **to's** there, at the very least, sounds awful.

**Better**: so she thought that finding a seat in a nearly empty car so easily on that hot steamy Tuesday was paradoxical.

Also, the repetition of "find something to be" and find a thing [seat] is also poor style.

Comment: Perfect answer. 99% of my confusion was because of the use of "one hot, steamy Tuesday" in the middle of the sentence. 1% maybe was because of the use of two "to's" that makes the sentence a little weird but I could tolerate it :) 

Finally, I did not even notice "find" has been used twice in the sentence. I recognized this only after reading your answer. I also read your useful link about theme/rheme construction.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi Yes, that one, hot steamy Tuesday in the middle was a nuisance....:)

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing some of the comments:

I followed the link to the book. It seems to be a pretty popular book for cramming vocabulary for  standardized entrance exams. It may work well if all you care about is learning the meanings of the words for a multiple choice test. Do not use it to learn English grammar or as a model for good writing.

The smallest fix I can think of for this single part of this particular sentence would be to say

> ...  found it paradoxical that on one hot ...

Even that is only a partial fix. "Strange" or "surprising" would be a better word than "paradoxical".